# How to loop through the array given as function parameter

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I would like to iterate through all array (passed to function as parameter) elements. The error i am getting is:
./file: line x: ${$ARR[@]}: bad substitution
Any suggestions how to solve this?
The parameter i am passing to function is just name of the array, so basically, all i want to substitute is the $ARR in the for loop by the specific array name

Comment: Is your question: "Given the name of an array `$name = myarray` and an array `declare -a my_array`, how can I use `$name` to access `my_array`"?

Comment: I might also be the case that you are looking for `${!name[@]}` (search for "indirect expansion" in [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)).